# How to pass use sync_to_async with a chain of methods

Tags: python, django, python-asyncio

I have a case like the following:

```py
async def handler(self):
   await sync_to_async(Stock.objects.filter)(id__in=product_stock).update(is_filled=False)
```

Where I am trying to pass the product_stock to the filter method then call the update on the filtered queryset.
I understand that I can wrap the logic in another method and just pass it the arg as in the following:

```py
@classmethod
def update_stocks(
    cls, product_stock: List[uuid.UUID]
) -> None:
    """Update stocks for order products."""
    cls.objects.filter(id__in=product_stock).update(is_filled=False)


async def handler(self):
   await sync_to_async(Stock.update_stocks)(product_stock=product_stock)
```

But is is possible to do it all as in my attempt above which doesn't work of course since the result is a courotine and not a django queryset? I want to avoid having to use another method just for this if it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a Django user but I think this is an operator precedence issue.  The `sync_to_async` function returns another function (an async one), so for the sake of clarity imagine your first handler function looks like this instead:

```
async def handler(self):
    f = sync_to_async(Stock.objects.filter)
    await f(id__in=product_stock).update()
```

Since `await` binds more weakly than `.`, the last line is equivalent to:

```
    await (f(id__in=product_stock).update())
```

which is not what you want, since the returned value from f() is a coroutine and so it doesn't have an update() method.

What you want is this, which applies the update() call to the returned value from coroutine `f`:

```
    (await f(id__in=product_stock)).update()
```

or, reverting to your original approach:

```
(await sync_to_async(Stock.objects.filter)(id__in=product_stock)).update(is_filled=False)
```

I honestly think that all those parenthesis are kind of ugly and I might prefer the approach with an extra function anyway.  But that's a matter of taste.  I think it should work.